# quick to install and set up FTP server on homebrew for OSX

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, homebrew, ftp

I need the smallest and easiest FTP server just to grab some files during development.

Homebrew has a discrete selection `brew search ftp` but I'm unsure which is the quickest to setup.

I don't want to use the builtin FTP server.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of writing, `brew search ftp` returns the following FTP servers:

- pure-ftpd
- vsftpd
- proftpd

Based on their websites, `pure-ftpd` appears to be your best choice for easy installation.

### pure-ftpd

> Beginners can install a [Pure-FTPd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd) server in 5 minutes. It can be as simple as installing the package, typing `pure-ftpd &` and… that’s all. You already have a running server, and clients can start to connect.

So for the two step, install and set to start each boot commands:

```
brew install pure-ftpd
brew services start pure-ftpd
```

### vsftpd

> [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) is a GPL licensed FTP server for UNIX systems, including Linux. It is secure and extremely fast. It is stable.

### ProFTPD

> [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org) grew out of the desire to have a secure and configurable FTP server, and out of a significant admiration of the Apache web server.

Comment: How to download file after installation

Comment: @nil96 please [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). A new question will attract attention and hopefully answers.

Answer (score 3):

Strange that no one mentioned the simplest way, which is to just load the built-in FTP server:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

It does work fine in 10.12 Sierra. However, it might not be available anymore in 10.13 High Sierra.

Comment: Agreed. I get the OP has reasons for not wanting to use the supplied FTP server. However, a reminder how easy to enable it is quite helpful and worth a +1

Comment: This has disabled in 10.14 Mojave

Answer (score 2):

Google brought me to this answer, so thought I would update with my findings. I use [ftp-srv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv) on node which is very quick to set up and run on the command line `ftp-srv [url] [options]` and can serve from a directory of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I do have OSX Mojave, and I ended up doing this:

```
brew install inetutils
```

and it worked perfectly. Hope it helps!

Comment: I did this, but could not find out how to setup an ftp server on my mac. I need this to test my ftp based installation procedure for a particular project.

Comment: I believe this installs the FTP client, but not the server.

Comment: i see ... even the thread title talks about a server :-) thanks