# Set up FTP server on macOS High Sierra (ProFTPD)

Tags: macos, high-sierra, ftp

I want to set up an FTP server on macOS High Sierra. (FTP is removed from macOS High Sierra, unlike previous versions.)

Since I have to use the other application connecting to the FTP server (my Mac), I cannot replace FTP with other protocols.

I know [a way](http://osxdaily.com/2018/08/07/get-install-ftp-mac-os/) to connect to the FTP server. However, I cannot find the way to run my Mac as an FTP server, not FTP client.

I follow [this](https://opikanoba.org/tech/proftpd-macos) page to use ProFTPD, but I failed to run the FTP server.

[image]

How can I set up the FTP server on macOS High Sierra?

Comment: A couple of things to get started...first, it's important to paste the *text* of the output as an image is not searchable and secondly, the error message is in relation to your proftpd.conf file.  Can you supply it so we can review?

Comment: ProFTPD may not be the best choice - reading some reviews it's aiming to be industrial strength and not perhaps the easiest to install and configure.  Do you have homebrew installed?  If so, this answer may be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141633/quick-to-install-and-set-up-ftp-server-on-homebrew-for-osx

Comment: @IanMcGowan I think my question is same with the question you linked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used pure-ftpd instead of ProFTPD. It is simpler.

After I installed pure-ftpd using brew,

```
brew install pure-ftpd
```

I configured the FTP (username-password) setting referring to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pure-FTPd

And then start FTP server.

```
brew services start pure-ftpd
```